# Whats the difference between UIDocumentBrowserViewController vs UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: ios

Whats the difference between UIDocumentBrowserViewController vs UIDocumentPickerViewController, And is it enough to use UIDocumentPickerViewController itself as of now ?

Comment: No it's not "enough". They are two quite different things. Use the one you need. Or neither.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Kind of old question now, but from [WWDC 2018 Session 216: Managing Documents In Your iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/216/), they state that the main difference is that the **Document Picker is meant for quick user interaction while the Document Browser is meant to be the main document browsing UI of your app**.

[image: Document Picker vs Document Browser]

I recommend watching the session (about 10 minutes in) for more details.

Answer (score -2):

Long story short:

`UIDocumentBrowserViewController` is much like the Files app on your iPhone which handles a lot for you like iCloud sync and sharing for example. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller

`UIDocumentPickerViewController` is just for accessing files in your file system: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

Comment: Not completely true. UIDocumentPickerViewController also lets you access cloud files. The difference is, do you want something that is the entry point of your app where you choose a file to edit it, when you are document-based, or do you want to pick a file to for example attach it to an email, but not edit that file?

Comment: @ThomasDeniau Does that mean for implementing a file picker for my app, i only have to use UIDocumentPickerViewController regardless the iOs version ?

Comment: Yes, but the picker is completely different before iOS 11 and after iOS 11 so beware. And on iOS pre-11 your users might be accustomed to see a document menu view controller. (But iOS 11 is a good deployment target nowadays anyway)